# How to print top row in bold when writing dataframe to excel in R using write.xlsx

Tags: r, r-xlsx

I write a dataframe in R to an excel file using the following command: `write.xlsx(dataframe, pathName, row.names = FALSE, append = FALSE)`.

Now I want to print the first row (headers in the dataframe) in bold. Does anyone know how to do this with the `write.xlsx` function from the `xlsx` package?

Comment: instead of writing your dataframe via the `write.xlsx` function, you can use the other resources of the xlsx package to create a workbook, set a font style [see here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xlsx/versions/0.5.7/topics/CellStyle) then write and close the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

You can use de `write_xlsx` function from the `writexl` package, setting `format_headers = TRUE`

```
write_xlsx(x, path = "your path", col_names = TRUE, format_headers = TRUE)
```